# Constructing self-complementary regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

It can be easily shown that if a graph is self-complementary and regular then the number of vertices, $n$, is equal to $4k +1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But, how to we prove (prove by constructing) that there is a self-complementary regular graph for $n = 4k +1$

Comment: Where have you seen that problem? I would be so interested in an answer...

Comment: “[Self-complementary graphs and generalisations: a comprehensive reference Manual](http://www.alastairfarrugia.net/sc-graph/sc-graph-survey.pdf)” by Alastair Farrugia has Chapter 3 “Regular Self-Complementary Graphs”

Answer (score 3):

Here is a source for a construction:

S.B. Rao, [On regular and strongly-regular self-complementary graphs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X85900639#). Discrete Mathematics **54** (1985), pp. 73–82.

See Theorem 2.3. This solution seems to answer a more specific question, so it's likely that there is a simpler answer to your question, which I would be interested in.